# Android: how to check what proguard removed

Tags: android, gradle

I'm pretty sure that proguard is removing something that I specifically told it not to remove.

Where is the log file that shows what was removed. When I try to search for this question, all find is posts about "removing Logging with proguard".

further more what is the wording used to indicate something was removed, so I can search through the log file.